# move a UIView according to the progressView's Progress

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, swift2

well am trying to make this UI :

[image: UI Image]

the above UI contains a ProgressView on  UITableViewCell and  the vertical line is a UIView (if i should use something else then a UIView for this vertical line then please do provide your suggestions )  well am stuck in moving this vertical line ? how can i place this line at the point where the bar is filled as shown in the image , if anybody knows then please let me it'll be so helpful for me

the pseudocode for what i need will be like

```
verticleLine.xAxisPostion = progressBar.progress.xAxis
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to think out of the box here: maybe you could use a `UISlider` instead with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false`? With `UISlider` you can specify not only the track color, but also the thumb image (being a tiny plain grey vertical bar in your case).

To expand a little bit: you set the `minimumTrackTintColor` to green, the `maximumTrackTintColor` to red (or stretchable images for `minimum/maximumTrackImage`), `minimumValue` to `0`, `maximumValue` to `1`. Instead of `progress` you can now use `value` — and it should give you roughly the same behaviour with the thumb (grey bar) following the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

> the above UI contains a ProgressView

Don't use a UIProgressView. Just create your own self-drawing view that looks exactly the way you want it to. The view that you've designed — green to the left of the progress point, red to the right of the progress point, and a vertical line right at the progress point — is trivial to draw, and trivial to redraw when progress happens (i.e. when the value changes).